# Spark Mongo DB Connection - MongoDB Version lesser than 3.2

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using Spark. (Java Spark API)

When trying to run submit the job, it fails for the with the below error message ,

```
20/07/05 17:32:00 ERROR DefaultMongoPartitioner:
---------------------------------------- WARNING: MongoDB version < 3.2 detected.
----------------------------------------

With legacy MongoDB installations you will need to explicitly configure the Spark Connector with a partitioner.

This can be done by:  * Setting a "spark.mongodb.input.partitioner" in SparkConf.  * Setting in the "partitioner" parameter in ReadConfig.  * Passing the "partitioner" option to the DataFrameReader.

The following Partitioners are available:

 * MongoShardedPartitioner - for sharded clusters, requires read access to the config database.  * MongoSplitVectorPartitioner - for single nodes or replicaSets. Utilises the SplitVector command on the primary.  * MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner - creates a specific number of partitions. Slow as requires a query for every partition.  * MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner - creates partitions based on data size. Slow as requires a query for every partition.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The DefaultMongoPartitioner requires MongoDB >= 3.2
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.DefaultMongoPartitioner.partitions(DefaultMongoPartitioner.scala:58)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.getPartitions(MongoRDD.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1928)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1164)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
        at com.virtualpairprogrammers.JavaIntroduction.main(JavaIntroduction.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:750)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have tried the following options , but still throws the same error message,

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.app.id", "MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
        .set("partitioner", "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB", "64");
```

Let me know if i am missing something in here which is why it is throwing the error message.
Not able to identify why it still goes to DefaultMongoPartitioner

Thanks in Advance,
Sam

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/configuration/) that you hopefully read say *"If setting these connector input configurations via SparkConf, prefix these settings with spark.mongodb.input."* - so, why did you do it for all options but the partitioner? Why not `spark.mongodb.input.partitioner`?

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser : From the document i assumed that we need to mention Partitioner and the options for each partitioner. Because each partitioner has 3 or 4 options on how it can be handled.

Comment: I'd assume that all non-existing options for a specific partitioner will just be ignored. At least this would make sense to me. But in any case the conf option is `spark.mongodb.input.partitioner`

Comment: @UninformedUser - So are you telling to use something like this ?

`SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.app.id", "MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB", "64");`

Comment: well, at least that's how I understand the documentation, yes. And that's also mentioned in the stacktrace of the exception you got, to use `spark.mongodb.input.partitioner` as key. It's quite common for non-built-in Spark conf options to use a separate key prefix like `spark.mongodb` to avoid interference with other Spark connectors etc.

Comment: @UninformedUser - Thanks it is working for me. Can you post this as the Answer. I will vote for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with parameters sent,

Below are the correct format

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.app.id", "MongoSparkConnectorTour")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner")
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB", "64");
```

The issue is solved and i am able to connect and extract data without any issues